# Alternatives for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, mobile, visual-studio-2015, cross-platform

I was hoping someone would be able to help me out with a simple question. In Visual Studio 2015 I'm looking to build a mobile phone application, and I was hoping there is an alternative to using Xamarin, something a bit less complicated but still uses C#. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated, many thanks Dylan.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft adquired Xamarin, so if you develop in Windows OS you need to use Visual studio, otherwise, if you develop on Mac, you should use Xamarin Studio. But you should know that is not about the IDE, is about the platform. If you don't want to use C#, and want to build an hibrid mobile app you need to check [Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/)